# AJAX No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want real time get data from my database, but display error.
Ajax code here:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(

 function() {
     checkCustomer();


     check...... etc....



 }, 1000);

function checkCustomer() { //ajax to getCustomerTotal.php

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        customerTotal = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("customerTotal").innerHTML =  customerTotal;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "getCustomerTotal.php", false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

PHP Code here:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$query=mysql_query("select * from users");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $num_rows;
?>
```

Above is my code, if I set 1000 or 10000 millisecond then display 
"No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
If I set 30000 to 60000, then No Problem, but I need real-time.

Comment: Is this problem persists only in chrome or in all browsers?

Comment: why do you care about // code for IE6, IE5?

Comment: http or https protocol?

Comment: @VijayaSankarN this is effect of all browser and all computer.
If i open this page, another computer cant to run the website

Comment: @JaromandaX, i use http protocol

Answer (score 0):

There is some bugs in `AJAX` response sometimes it doesn't shows the result for a small time delay if we define a long time delay then there will be no problem. Same problem was with me I have find out the below solution. Try below `Ajax` code.

```
 <script>
                function showVal()
                {            

                    var xmlhttp;    
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("customerTotal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getCustomerTotal.php", true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }


            </script>
```

Comment: i try use _GET_ and _REQUEST_ method will no display the error. but will make my website speed down.

Comment: remove null value while sending request e.g. `xmlhttp.send()`